# How to pass data to textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created this method to view a list. And also created a partial view in JavaScript dialog function. The partial view is creating and showing my id, orderno,customerid which are I wanted. But problem is how I can get a value by selecting a raw from table. Here is my action method for creating a a list..

```
public ActionResult OrderList()
        {
            var ord = db.Query<OrderM>("Select * from OrderM");
            return PartialView(ord);
        }
```

here is my Partiview which showing my value in a table...

```
@model IEnumerable<testcon.OrderM>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OdrId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CId)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.CheckBox("OdrId", new { @id="chk"})
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderNo)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CId)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My create view page for for getting value

```
<div class="editor-field">
          Order No :@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrderNo)
            @*<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getOrderList()">Show Order</a>*@
        </div>
```

And my javascript are working wel.. but i don't know how i can get a value when i will select a data from table. Like OrderNo is my textbox id when i will select a data from orlist it textbox will get this id....

```
$('#orlist').dialog({
                     width: 500,
                     height: 350,
                     open: true,
                     title: 'Select Order',
                     buttons: {
                         Select: function () { },
                         Cancel: function () {
                             $('#orlist').dialog('close');
                             $('#orlist').empty();
                         }
                     }
                 });
```

Comment: what do you mean by " select a data from table"?

Comment: I have two views like create views and partialview orderlist. In my orderlist partial view i have a column name OrderNo. When i will select one rwo in partial view, The raw value of OrderNo in partial view will be add in create view OrderNo textbox. it will be like this partialview.orderno= createview.orderNo

Comment: No, you are talking about selecting data from the table. Table is not a dropdown or checkbox, so how you select the data?

Comment: @VladL boss now i have a checkbox of id, how i can pass partial view orderno to Create view orderno textbox.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's not clear, but item.WantedField should contain your wanted fields value in the list.
If you want to do it in *for*, you can use something like:

```
Model.ElementAt(i).WantedField
```

So you can reach it through an index in the Model.